# last insert ID of drupal_write_record

Tags: 7

I need to get the latest inserted id, this is the line im using for writing files to my db

```
drupal_write_record('file_managed', $file, 'fid');
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Use `$file->fid`.